# Can not sign in - The maximum number of free accounts have been activated on this iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-id

I have faced this problem in my iPhone - 
"The maximum number of free accounts have been activated on this iPhone".

For solving this problem I erase all content and settings of my iPhone and set it as a fresh new iPhone.

Still facing the same problem.

Can any one help me to achieve this as I have to logged in with multiple apple ids for testing in app purchase in my application to that device.

[image: Message seeing in iPhone after erasing]

Comment: You can remove the unused devices by logging into the account in the browser to use it on new IPhone device.

Comment: Thanks Harjot for replying. I removed my device from account but still getting same error.

Comment: no i didn't find .

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwibq8mDhY7jAhXbknAKHYFKBq8QFjACegQIDhAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fappletoolbox.com%2F2013%2F07%2Ficloud-the-maximum-number-of-free-accounts-have-been-activated-qa%2F&usg=AOvVaw0vfG8j0AF8aqhA9ZCNbZ0F

Comment: Same here, Actually I used number of Sanbox accounts! That's the mistake. But how to test IAP without sandbox account.

Answer (score 7):

I just now found a way how to avoid this issue.

You don't need to log in sandbox user account into Your actual iPhone sign in. [Dont sign in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuBjK.png)

Instead of this, You need to find in settings "iTunes and App Store" [find iTunes and App Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfTeu.png)

After that scroll down to the bottom until You see sign in for sandbox accounts [Sign in here all Your sandbox test accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JHhv.png)

It should not complain about the maximum number of accounts.

Comment: I don't have the "Sandbox Account" section in the "iTunes & App Stores" settings. How come? I've even tried logging in with different accounts, didn't help.

Comment: It crashes when I tap 'Sandbox account' nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from this:- https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

For more info check this:- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064

Comment: Thanks pooja for replying. I removed my device from account but still getting same error.

Comment: Apple currently limits all its iDevice products to a maximum number of free accounts–3 total iCloud accounts per iDevice. Any single iDevice creates up to a maximum of 3 iCloud accounts and these accounts are tied to your iDevice’s hardware, not your user account i.e. the restriction is attached to the iDevice itself. So you'll never be able to create another iCloud account on that iPhone or another iDevice. It’s an Apple hard rule so there’s no way around this set limit. If you already created all of your 3 iCloud accounts, you can’t create another iCloud account using that particular device.

Comment: Thanks but 4 to 5 times I erase all settings of my iphone and able to login with new apple id but in this time I couldn't signin with any id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in your newly created apple id to any idevices or mac, and after that sign out from it and re-sign in your apple id to the current device. It should help.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem in my Iphone 6. Guys follow this:
Just Create a NEW APPLE ID in APPLE DEVICE (ONLY APPLE) like MAC, IPHONES, TAB etc.
Now don't directly Go To Settings and login with the new APPLE ID, it may not work and will give the same error.
So Go to APP STORE and try downloading any APP, it will ask for APPLE ID & PASSWORD.
ENTER WHAT U CREATED.
But again it will direct u to another page where u need to enter some more details for ICLOUD & Then the APP will start downloading with the NEW APPLE ID after login again for downloading the APP from APP Store.

ALL THE BEST::::::::::::::::